# jquery: remove the selected value if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm displaying list of items with checkbox, if checkbox is checked the value of selected item is displayed in different div.

Now, if I uncheck the checkbox I should remove the items displayed in the div.
Please help me how to fix this?

```
$('input[name="selectedItems1"]').click(function(){
            if (this.checked) {                   

            }else{                    
                //what should go here
            }
        });
```

Comment: for that you need to share how you are adding the item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example can help you:

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val3" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**jquery**

```js
$('input[name="selectedItems1"]').click(function(){ 
  if (this.checked) {
    var span = "<span id='" + this.value + "'>" + this.value + "</span>";
    $("#result").append(span);
  }else{
    $("#" + this.value).remove();//what should go here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val3" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to accomplish your task. The following way also preserves the order in which the selected data is displayed.

```js
var selectedItemsContainer = $('#selected');
var items = $('input[name="items"]');

items.on('change', function(){
  
  selectedItemsContainer.empty();
  var appendData = '';
  
  $.each(items, function(i, item)
    {
      if ($(item).prop('checked'))
        {
          appendData +=$(item).val() + ' ';
        }
    });
  
    selectedItemsContainer.append(appendData);
            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="Data 1">Data 1
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="Data 2">Data 2
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="Data 3">Data 3
<br>
<div id="selected"></div>
```